# setTimeout Inside for loop not expected

Tags: javascript

I have small doubt in the below code

```
for(var i=1; i<6; i++) {
   console.log('Outside: ',i);
   setTimeout(function(){ console.log('Inside: ',i); }, 1000);
}
```

Result of above code: is

```
Outside: 1
Outside: 2
Outside: 3
Outside: 4
Outside: 5
Inside: 6
Inside: 6
Inside: 6
Inside: 6
Inside: 6
```

Can any one explain?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(i){ console.log('Inside: ',i); }, 1000, i);` Use the 3rd parameter of __setTimeout__

Comment: Never put a setTimeout inside a for loop. You use setTimeout based on recursive logic. And stop calling it when you're logic dictates the end of setTimeout looping.